# The proof of the proper mapping theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading Fischer's complex analytic geometry book. In page 64, we proved the proper mapping theorem. Which says

> Let $\varphi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper holomorphic map and denote by $\mathcal{K} \subset \mathcal{O}_Y$ the coherent sheaf of ideals which is the kernel of the canonical homomorphism
> $$
> \tilde{\varphi}: \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Y}} \rightarrow \varphi_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{X}} \text {. }
> $$
> Then the complex subspace $\varphi(X) \hookrightarrow Y$ determined by $\mathcal{K}$ has the following properties:$$|\varphi(\mathrm{X})|=|\varphi|(\mathrm{X})$$

The proof goes as follows:

Since $\varphi_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent and therefore $\mathcal{K}$ is coherent ,  $|\varphi|(X)$ being closed in $|Y|$ (by properness of the map) we have

for $q \in Y$,
$$
q \in|\varphi|(X) \Leftrightarrow\left(\varphi_* \mathcal{O}_X\right)_q \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{K}_q \neq \mathcal{O}_{Y, q} \Leftrightarrow q \in \operatorname{supp}\left(\mathcal{O}_Y / \mathcal{K}\right)
$$

---

Where the first "iff" due to coherence of the sheaf and the image is a closed subset, and the last "iff" is also clear by the definition.

The question is why the 2nd "iff" holds, in particular why $\mathcal{K}_q = \mathcal{O}_{Y,q} \implies (\varphi_* \mathcal{O}_X)_q = 0$?